# Complex analysis, finding value of the derivatives

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm stuck with an annoying problem:

Let $C$ be the ellipse $(x/2)^2 + (y/3) ^2 = 1$, traversed once in positive direction.

Define

$$G(z) := \int_C \frac{b^2 - b + 2}{b-z}\,db,$$

where $z$ is inside $C$.

Find $G(1)$, $G'(i)$ and $G''(-i)$. I got the right value for $G(1)$ and $G'(i)$ but $G''(-i)$, according to the theorem I'm using, I should be getting $2\pi i$ but the answer, according to my given solution it's supposed to be $4\pi i$. Is my given solution wrong or am I on the wrong track? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which theorem are you using?

Comment: It says that I can rewrite the integral as: 2 * pi* i* g^(m-1)(z0) / (m-1)! 
That's why I think I should have half of the given value, as, according to the theorem, it should be 4 * p i* i/2 = 2 * pi * i

Comment: What is $m$ there? There's no $m$ in the integral. Do you know a theorem that allows you to determine $G$ from the form of the integral?

Comment: Well, what I wrote up there is simply a rewrite o f^(n)(z) = n! / 2 * pi * i *integral of f(b)/(b-z)^(n+1) db, which can be rewrote as integral of f(b)/(b-z0)^m db

Comment: Apologizing for my writing, I realize the job of interpreting my question is harder than the question itself, I've promised myself to get better at that in the near future.

Comment: But there you have the factorial in the numerator. You seem to have dropped that somewhere.

Comment: Concerning the writing, [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) may help getting you started.

Comment: ahh, I think I found the problem, thank you sir for helping out, I totally missed that!